# Android Studio Import Project from ADT window not showing up

Tags: android, adt, sdl-2

Simple question here, but I haven't found anyone asking this. Also, keep in mind that I'm new to Android development.
So I've been learning SDL2, and got to a point where I'm trying to start making projects on mobile devices. I'm using Lazy foo's tutorial "hello mobile" on Windows, where I'm stuck on step 11, since the "Import Project from ADT (Eclipse Android)" window is not showing up after I import SDL2's "android-project" folder. I'm asking if I'm missing something or is there a way to import a destination directory another way.

When I try Debugging I get:

> Cause: executing external native build for ndkBuild D:\Programming\SDL2-2.0.8\SDL2-2.0.8\android-project\app\jni\Android.mk